# Can "decide" take a gerund as its direct object?

Tags: gerunds

I've come across these sentence written by English novelists by googling.
(I've confirmed that they're English native speakers by googling their names)

> 1. After a while, finding that nothing more happened, she decided going into the garden at once.
> 2. I decided going into my white room.

But I've already learnt that when I want to use "decide" with "gerund", I must write it with "on" as in "I decided on going into my white house", but as I don't think this seems to be not entirely correct as I've come across exceptions to this,
I wouldn't think they might've written grammatically incorrect sentences as they're experts at writing books.

Comment: Neither of your example sentences is complete. You need to add something like *was a good idea* to the end.

Comment: @JasosnBassford then, you think the authors must have omitted something in both sentences on purpose?

Comment: I have no idea. It could have just been a mistake. The use of the gerund itself isn't wrong—but neither of these sentences uses it correctly.

Comment: @Floret In the first one, which is from [Alice in Wonderland](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Alice%27s_Adventures_in_Wonderland_(1866)/Chapter_1), it's "decided on going"--you've omitted the "on" which you can see at section 12 in this link.

Comment: @Katy oh.. well well, where I saw the sentence, "on" is omitted, unlike your link.

Comment: @JasonBassford is there a sentence in which we can use "decide" with "a gerund of its object"?

Comment: The second sentence appares to be from *Paranoid Lost* by Greg Bauder, and I found it on page 86 of the edition in Google Books.  I had never before heard of this book or author. I see no obvious reason for the absence of "on" here, and I suspect a mistake, whether by author, editor, or publisher I have no way to know.

Comment: @Floret Do you mean using a *decide [gerund]* form without an intervening preposition or a concluding statement? I can't think of one off the top of my head. (I think not, but I couldn't say with certainty.)

Comment: Ok, I got it! should I delete this question as they're just wrong sentences?

Comment: The version of *Alice* at http://www.gutenberg.org/files/11/11-h/11-h.htm also has "decided on"

Comment: One could write: "I wasn't sure what to do. I decided going into my white room." meanign that the person made the decision while going into the room, but this would be better with "while" included.

Comment: @DavidSiegel in that case, "going" is used as a present participle, though.

Comment: @DavidSiegel it'd be a very boring stuff to ask why "decide" cannot take a gerund of its direct object, but anyways, could you tell me any reasons why it sounds wrong if possible? I have no ideas why.

Comment: @floret I honestly cannot formulate a clear rule on this. It is no doubt something I absorbed over years of use.

Comment: @David Siegel then, do even native speakers have to learn which verb is correct to take a gerund or infinitive as its direct object one by one?

Comment: There was a similar issue that was answered back in 2013, see if this helps: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78170/difference-between-decided-on-and-decided-to

Comment: @floret I think the answer linked to by Kareb987, and the answer given below by James K are good. I have nothing to add to the combination. A native speaker does indeed learn such things one at a tiem, but mostly not consciously and explicitly, rather by imitation and experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Decide" does not take a gerund as its direct object. It can take a "to infinitive".

The first example you give is simple error in the quoted source. The original has "decided on going into the garden". Unlike "decide", the phrasal verb "decide on" can be followed by a gerund.

The second may be an error (of the author, publisher or printer). It could be interpreted as a participle phrase, mean "While I was going into my white room, I decided (something)".  That interpretation is possible, but unlikely. It would not be a well-written sentence (due to the confusion with a gerund), therefore I think that an error is more likely, and the author intended "decided on...".

Native speakers do learn which verbs take a gerund, which take an infinitive, which can take both, and which take either but with a different meaning. It is part of the learning that takes place during the hours and hours that an infant spends listening to its parents and then to its friends. There are aspects of your language that are just as difficult for English speakers to learn!